# NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription inside library Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location

I've built a Swift library that uses CoreLocation for fetching user location when the app is in use. If I want to integrate my library inside an app, I only need to import the library, instantiate my class and start the method that gets user location...

...And I also need to add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` inside the app Info.plist!

I was wondering if it is possible to add the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` inside the library Info.plist to let the programmer choose if implement a custom description or leave the default library description.

P.S. I've already added the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` inside the library Info.plist, but Xcode is not happy if I decide not to add it also in the app Info.plist:

`This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data`

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

You will need to instruct the library user that they need to add the location usage key to their app's info.plist.

They will need to add a description that is appropriate for their app's usage of location